# How to add a fading gradient to NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, gradient, nstextview

I have a `NSTextView`, which is displayed over an `NSImageView`.
The text view displays lyrics of a song over the artwork.

I would like to apply a little fading gradient at the bottom of the text view.
The background is an image which varies, so I can't just draw a straight gradient.

I guess you could just redraw the image on top of the text view, but this doesn't seem to be a very good solution.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

Comment: Hmm. Reading this again, are you looking to fade the background, or the text itself?

Comment: @PeterHosey I'd like to fade the text itself